# using a field with a Boolean type in dexie.js

Tags: javascript, dexie

Does not work select by value true. Please tell me what is the problem?

```
const db = new Dexie('ToDo_DB');

db.version(1).stores({
    list: '++id, task, dateTime, done'
});

db.list.clear();

db.list.add({task: "1 task", dateTime: Date.now(), done: true});
db.list.add({task: "2 task", dateTime: Date.now(), done: false});
db.list.add({task: "3 task", dateTime: Date.now(), done: true});
db.list.add({task: "4 task", dateTime: Date.now(), done: false});

db.list.where('done').equals(false).each(function(item) {
    console.log('Found: ' + item.task + ' with date ' + item.dateTime);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Booleans cannot be indexed in Dexie. See the doco: https://dexie.org/docs/Indexable-Type

> The following javascript types are possible to index:
>
> - string
> - number
> - Date
> - Arrays of strings, numbers, Dates or a mix of those.
> - ArrayBuffer (IndexedDB 2.0 only)
> - Typed arrays (IndexedDB 2.0 only)
>
> Note that all other types are non-indexable, including:
>
> - **boolean**
> - undefined
> - Object
> - null

I'm trying to think of a good alternative to this at the moment but a simple solution would be to use a number with 0=false and 1=true. This has the benefit that you can still rely on the index of the database to do your query:

```
const db = new Dexie('ToDo_DB');

db.version(1).stores({
    list: '++id, task, dateTime, done'
});

db.list.clear();

db.list.add({task: "1 task", dateTime: Date.now(), done: 1});
db.list.add({task: "2 task", dateTime: Date.now(), done: 0});
db.list.add({task: "3 task", dateTime: Date.now(), done: 1});
db.list.add({task: "4 task", dateTime: Date.now(), done: 0});

db.list.where('done').equals(0).each(function(item) {
    console.log('Found: ' + item.task + ' with date ' + item.dateTime);
});
```

If you don't have much data in your store and don't need to index, you can use your own [filter()](https://dexie.org/docs/Collection/Collection.filter()) functions, like:

```
const db = new Dexie('ToDo_DB');

db.version(1).stores({
    list: '++id, task, dateTime, done'
});

db.list.clear();

db.list.add({task: "1 task", dateTime: Date.now(), done: true});
db.list.add({task: "2 task", dateTime: Date.now(), done: false});
db.list.add({task: "3 task", dateTime: Date.now(), done: true});
db.list.add({task: "4 task", dateTime: Date.now(), done: false});

db.list.filter(e => e.done === false).each(function(item) {
    console.log('Found: ' + item.task + ' with date ' + item.dateTime);
});
```

If you have large objects (with blobs) or lots of records, this is probably not a very performant option. You should use the index instead.